# Why is the critical angle the largest angle of incidence for which refraction can still occur?

Tags: definition, refraction

When I look up "critical angle", it's defined like the following:

> The critical angle is the angle of incidence where the angle of refraction is 90°

[image: img1]

<sub>[source](https://intl.siyavula.com/read/science/grade-11/geometrical-optics/05-geometrical-optics-07)</sub>

If I look up what refraction means, I get this:

> The changing of a light ray’s direction when it **passes through variations in matter** is called refraction.

The refracted ray in the above illustration seems to be in the middle, not passing through a medium, yet it's called refraction.

Comment: It’s pointing out that there is an angle at which there is no more refraction, and beyond which, there is only reflection. That is, in the top one there technically isn’t any refraction, though this author states that the refracted angle is 90 degrees. It’s slightly confusing yes, but refraction means there has to be transmission of the incident ray into the new medium.

Comment: @josephh The "refracted" ray stays in the same medium then?

Comment: It lies on the interface between the two mediums.